# Composer keeps trying to load repo from old path

Tags: composer-php, satis

I have several private repos stored on Github and made available on Packagist.
Due to some stability issue, these packages were later moved into private Bitbucket and added to our private Satis. (removed from Packagist)

The issue is that when we try to run 'composer update' on our machine it still tries to pull from Github paths.

I have tried everything including:

- Deleted everything in the current folder to pull again
- Clear cache with the new clear-cache command and also with rm -rf

Nothing worked.

Is this considered a bug? What do I have to do to make sure composer never tries to use the old repo path?

(I posted this on Composer issues as well but haven't got any solution there yet)

Comment: Try "packagist": "false" and remove repos that are in packagist and  see whether it installs the private repos. If you show your `composer.json` it may be helpful for other to give more insight.

Comment: Did you try deleting your lock file to update?

Comment: Not sure why a moderator deleted my answer. It was the correct answer for those who may get frustrated with the same issue. I had to contact the maintainer of Packagist to have their cache flushed out, then after that everything works fine.